# Locale definition produces two parse trees

Tags: parsing, isabelle

Here is my simple locale definition in Isabelle:

```
locale sig =
  fixes le:: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" (infixl "≤" 50)
  assumes refl: "x ≤ x"
```

Now, I get an error message:

```
Ambiguous input⌂ produces 2 parse trees:
  ("\<^const>HOL.Trueprop"
    ("\<^const>Orderings.ord_class.less_eq" ("_position" x) ("_position" x)))
  ("\<^const>HOL.Trueprop" ("\<^fixed>le" ("_position" x) ("_position" x)))
Ambiguous input
2 terms are type correct:
  (x ≤ x)
  (x ≤ x)
Failed to parse prop
```

Do I have a conflict with a builtin less-or-equal operator?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `≤` operator is defined in the `ord` typeclass, so you could just extend this class:

```
class sig = ord +
  assumes refl: "x ≤ x"
```

Other alternatives:

- Do not import the definition of `ord`
- Hide the existing notation with `no_notation Orderings.ord_class.less_eq ("(_/ ≤ _)"  [51, 51] 50)` (see [hiding operators to avoid ambiguities in the AST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103497/hiding-operators-to-avoid-ambiguities-in-the-ast))
- Use a different name or symbol